# How do I find out what project is connected to Youtube data API service based on the project number?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I got an email stating that my project(s) hasn't accessed or used the YouTube Data API Service in the last 60 days and if it's inactive for another 30 days they'll disable access to the API. The project is referenced only by a number, and I have no idea what the "project" is or how to find it based on that number.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya It is on-topic; it is reference to the Google API which is used for programming projects

Comment: I also received this email and have no idea how to figure out which app it's talking about. I'd love to get an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same email. I eventually found the Project by stumbling my way to this part of my Google Account, so you should find the Project in your Google Account using the same link:

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/

In my case the Project relates to the Wordpress Plugin "YouTube Lyte":

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-youtube-lyte/

I installed this Plugin on a Wordpress self-hosted blog some years ago.

I have no idea why my Google Developer Console identifies me (ie. my Google Account) as the "Owner" of the "YouTube Lyte" api.

I will see if I can get any clarification via the YouTube Lyte Plugin Support Page:

https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-youtube-lyte

This is not my highest priority at the moment so someone else might get there first - and maybe kindly post an answer here?

Liz

Comment: For myself, the project ID doesn't even exist on my console

Comment: Same for me @Crimbo. The console shows that I have no projects at all. The lack of information made me think it was a scam email, but I checked anyway to see if any of my projects would be affected. I guess when I have no projects at all, none of them will be affected either XD... I'll keep an eye on this thread.

Comment: Same here @JerkMan. I still can't find the project number anywhere.

Comment: I wonder if the email was sent by error

Comment: We just got this email too, only the project has already been disabled.  Where do you see the Project ID?  Our Google projects all have names, not numbers.